# How i use product designer for product image for frontend in magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, frontend, catalog

I want use image editor for product image
[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you purchased a third-party  Extension?

Comment: No, i want to create custom with my code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below extension for the same requirement.

https://www.aitoc.com/magento-2-custom-product-designer.html

Apart from that, To create the custom module, you have to collect the information/libraries from different-different places as per your requirements.